# CSS grid - fixed height scrolling container prevents inner background from taking up full height

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a scrolling div with a fixed height, inside is a scrollbar, a header and some content. I would like the sidebar to take up the full height of the fixed height container, however the background is limited to the scroll height and gets cut off.

The wrapper cannot be set to scroll.

In the snippet below this can be seen by scrolling the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
}
 
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "Sidebar Header" "Sidebar Main";
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: Sidebar;
  background: red;
}

.header {
  grid-area: Header;
  background: blue
}

.main {
  grid-area: Main;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Main</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried simply removing `height: 100%;` and it seems to do what you're asking I think.

Comment: move the scroll to the wrapper? it's more logical

Comment: Removing height forces the whole page to scroll, the wrapper can't be set to scroll in this case, it has to be a fixed region with an inner scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Replace height with min-height and apply the scroll to wrapper instead:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
 
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "Sidebar Header" "Sidebar Main";
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: Sidebar;
  background: red;
}

.header {
  grid-area: Header;
  background: blue
}

.main {
  grid-area: Main;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Main</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case the wrapper can't be set to scroll (added to the question), setting the height to min-height then overflows the height of the container.